# Data Marketplace Piracy

Tags: data-marketplace

What prevents somebody from purchasing a data stream and then dumping all the data online somewhere, allowing others access without paying?

Comment: In Iota protocol there nothing to prevent that. It's more a "licensing" problem, unrelated to Iota.

Comment: If the creator of the data stream sees their data flowing freely on the Internet, he might stop providing that data stream, causing a lose-lose situation. Obviously this will not deter vandalism. :-(

Comment: @ben75, just because it's not tackled in the current IOTA protocol it doesn't mean it's unrelated to IOTA.

Comment: @Helmar It is unrelated to the IOTA protocol. The [Data Marketplace](https://data.iota.org/) allows participants to "Choose, Pay, and Access" data. IOTA enables Feeless Microtransactions and Secure Data Anchoring. Other than that, what participants choose to do with the purchased data (legal or not) is of little concern to IOTA. IOTA is the platform, not a regulator.

Comment: @Zass that's correct it's not IOTA protocol related. (Other than it's missing a DRM component which would complicate such actions.) That doesn't mean however that the question is unrelated to IOTA. Technologies that do not care enough about privacy and security generally fail.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: Nothing

Long Answer: It is exactly the same with music and TV series. They also get re-uploaded illegally in the darknet.

This problem is, however, unrelated to IOTA and as ben75 already said in his comment `more a 'licensing' problem`.

As a result of this data publishers may increase their prices, so rebroadcasters have to pay more. As a result, they will also have to charge a fee, to reach break even.

However, using "rebroadcasted" data is everything but save! The "rebroadcaster" could easily change the decrypted data and republish "fake news" instead. Therefore I do not think this will become a major issue in the future as most users will be advised to stay with the "official" sources

Comment: This is full of assumptions that the problems of the printing and broadcasting industries show are incorrect. There are tons of fakes of books and series out there so the only question is what you consider major. Each of theses low quality fakes diminishes the quality of the original product.